# WPF DataGrid, getting cell value

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I need to get cell value from `SelectedItem` of DataGrid.

Here is DataGrid XAML code:

```
<DataGrid CanUserReorderColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,11,0,0" Name="dataGridCards" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="288" SelectionChanged="dataGridCards_SelectionChanged">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Card ID" Binding="{Binding cardID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Card Name" Binding="{Binding cardName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Set Mark" Binding="{Binding setMark}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I blocked column reorder and used:

```
object row = dataGridCards.SelectedItem;
cardName = (dataGridCards.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock).Text;
```

DataGrid displays join of two tables. I really don't like this solution, I prefer not to block reordering. How can I get cell value without block reordering? Do I need to define some patterns for DataGrid rows?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem... can't you just access `row.PropertyName` to find your cell value?

Comment: I can't see properties.

Comment: What type of objects do you have in the `DataGrid`?

Comment: @pochmurnik, that's because you treat SelectedItem as `object`. Cast it to the type it really is (`Card` or whatever) and don't try to work poor DataGrid as though it belongs to Win Forms world.

Comment: Right now I think I solved the problem. I prepared a class that handle join result and then inserted whole list into DataGrid.

@Sheridan, I missed my own definition of objects.

Comment: @icebat, I try to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: @pochmurnik, I'm glad that you have solved the problem. However, as this question is now unlikely to help anyone apart from you, please close it using the close button.

Comment: I'm new here, I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a class to populate `dataGrid`:

```
class RowCardSet
{
    private int cardID;
    private String cardName;
    private String setMark;

    public RowCardSet(int cardID, String cardName, String setMark)
    {
        this.cardID = cardID;
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.setMark = setMark;
    }

    public int CardID
    {
        get { return this.cardID; }
        set { this.cardID = value; }
    }

    public String CardName
    {
        get { return this.cardName; }
        set { this.cardName = value; }
    }

    public String SetMark
    {
        get { return this.setMark; }
        set { this.setMark = value; }
    }
}
```

In that case I also needed to change Binding in `dataGrid`. From `cardID`, `cardName`, `setMark` to `CardID`, `CardName` and `SetMark`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Card ID" Binding="{Binding CardID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Card Name" Binding="{Binding CardName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Set Mark" Binding="{Binding SetMark}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Here is the query to populate `dataGrid`:

```
public static List<RowCardSet> GetCardSetList(int setID, DataContext dataContext)
    {
        return (from cardItem in dataContext.Cards
                join setItem in dataContext.Sets
                on cardItem.setID equals setItem.setID
                where cardItem.setID == setID
                select new RowCardSet(
                    cardItem.cardID,
                    cardItem.cardName,
                    setItem.setMark)).ToList();
    }
```

So now I can populate using this method: `dataGridCards.ItemsSource = Queries.GetCardSetList(setID, dataContext);`

and getting a specific value looks like this:

```
String cardName = ((RowCardSet)dataGridCards.SelectedItem).CardName.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the column header to find the current index, then use that:

```
object row = dataGridCards.SelectedItem;
int columnIndex = dataGridCards.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.Equals("Card Name")).DisplayIndex;
String cardName = (dataGridCards.SelectedCells[columnIndex].Column.GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock).Text;
```